# SQL Computed Column, Using LEFT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following TSQL that works great as a query, but not if i put it into my computed column area.

Basically I have a field in my table that should take the value from another column and give me back only the first 3 characters.

I have a column called `Day` that holds weekdays data such as: monday, tuesday, thursday.

I have another column called `DayShort` that should have the same weekday but shortened such as: mon, tue, thu

```
SELECT LEFT(Day, 3) AS DayShort FROM Courses
```

Comment: And the problem is?....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE Courses ADD DayShort AS (LEFT(Day,3));
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, will accept soon as timer lets me 10mins.